# Can not delete item by using mongoose query?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

This is my source code to delete a specific id:

```
router.delete('/api/items/:id', async (req, res) => {
    res.json(req.params.id);
    try {
        const deleteItem = await todoItemModel.deleteOne({ id: req.params.id });
        res.status(200).json('Item deleted successfully');
    } catch (err) {
        res.json(err);
    }
})
```

---

RESTful Client:

DELETE http://localhost:5000/api/items/62f9ce3acb74841984127399
Content-Type: application/json

---

Error detail:

```
node:internal/errors:465
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\thait\Projects\todo-list-mern\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\thait\Projects\todo-list-mern\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:174:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\thait\Projects\todo-list-mern\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:278:15)
    at C:\Users\thait\Projects\todo-list-mern\server\src\routes\items.js:26:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this line.

```
res.json(req.params.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try once with this code?

```
router.delete('/api/items/:id', async (req, res) => {
    res.json(req.params.id);
    try {
        const deleteItem = await todoItemModel.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.id });
        return res.status(200).json('Item deleted successfully');
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({err});
    }
})
```